# Is there a configuration to Hibernate Multi tenancy update all databases?

Tags: hibernate, multi-tenant

I'm using Hibernate with multi tenancy and I find problems when the classes are changed, e.g new attributes, when I start up my Wildfly server only the default database is updated, Is threre a way to configure hibernate to update all databases?

Follow the configuration of my  entityManagerFacotory:

```
<bean depends-on="dataSource" id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="xx.xxx.xxxxxx.xxx" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="TesteJpa" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">DATABASE</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">xx.xxx.xxxxx.routingds.SchemaResolver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider">xx.xxx.xxxxxx.routingds.MultiTenantProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.search.suseIndex.directory_provider">filesystem</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.search.suseIndex.indexBase">C:\xxx\indexes</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I tried the property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update, but this seems not work, and generated an error: Could not complete schema update: java.lang.NullPointerException.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: See it as an advice -> Do not use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update in production. Its just for development.

Comment: Ok, I will cut off this property, but how to update all databases? Is there a configuration for it or I will have to do workaround solution?

Comment: I am having the same question for multiple databases urls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260619/hbm2dll-initialization-in-hibernate-jpa-with-multiple-databases-multitenancy

Comment: TableGenerator and doesn't support multitenancy.

In this rejected issue (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7389) there's a workaround