# Hbm2dll initialization in Hibernate JPA with multiple databases + Multitenancy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, initialization, multi-tenant, ddl

**How do I initialize multiple databases with hbm2dll using LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean?**

I am using different datasources per tenant in MultiTenancy.
I have a default datasource with id "dataSource" in ApplicationContext.xml and I generate a datasource per tenant using the properties of "dataSource" but changing the url. I add them in a custom MapDataSourceLookup.

I have tried to configure JPA initialization using LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory" >
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.dialect}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value-ref="multitenancyConnectionProvider"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value-ref="tenantResolver"/>                                              
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="pum" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="dataSourceLookup" ref="dataSourceLookup"/>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${database.idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />
    <property name="idleMaxAge" value="${database.idleMaxAge}" />
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="${database.maxConnectionsPerPartition}" />
    <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="${database.minConnectionsPerPartition}" />
    <property name="partitionCount" value="${database.partitionCount}" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${database.acquireIncrement}" />
    <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="${database.statementsCacheSize}" />
    <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="${database.releaseHelperThreads}" />
</bean>
```

I have a custom @component dataSourceLookup that is injected, and it's creating the different datasources in this way.

```
        //Add new datasource with configuration from "dataSource" and new url per tenant
        BoneCPDataSource customDataSource = new BoneCPDataSource(defaultDataSource.getConfig());
        customDataSource.setJdbcUrl(props.getProperty("database.url"));
        addDataSource(tenantId, customDataSource);

        logger.info("Configuring tenant: " + tenantId + " Properties: " + customDataSource.toString());
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">      
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>     
    <properties>            
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />         

        <!--  Multi-tenancy properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Right now the only scheme that is being created is the default database. But the datasources which point to other databases are not being created. That produce this error when I try to access to an user since USER table doesn't exist:

Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USER

Answer (score 0):

I got to solve it by using an custom extended class of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and implementing the method postProcessEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf, PersistenceUnitInfo pui).

In that method, I loop different datasources and create entitymanagerfactory using that datasource in each iteration, I know it is not the best but if you knew a better solution, I would like to listen :). Schemaexport is not supported by hibernate in multitenancy at the moment and this is the solution that I found.